# How to create Onboarding / WalkThrough inside first show screens?

Tags: android

i want to make users familiar with my app that they install first time by some beauty guides and i searched without clear answers but onboarding and walkThrough titles.
i want something like that.

[image: guides like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can control if is the first launch of the app and then show to the user the Onboarding screens.

First launch -> You can control it using SharedPreferences.

To create the OnBoarding -> You can use Viewpager with transparents Fragments and show the user how the app works.

I hope it can help you to figure out how to do it.

Viewpager: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide

SharedPreferences: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

OnBoarding sample: https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/onboarding-android-viewpager-google-way/

Happy coding.

Comment: You have idea how items in bottom navigation will be shown with every fragment ?

Comment: You can create each view as a layout without need to create the bottom view. Treat is a single fragments with a single layout. The bottom navigation will be behind it when the user skip the onBoarding screen